# Cardinality of the set of linear discontinuous functionals in a normed space

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

How does one show (or disprove) that for any infinite-dimensional normed vector space $V$, there are uncountably many linearly independent elements in $V^{*}\setminus V'$, where $V^{*}$ and $V'$ denote the algebraic dual and continuous dual respectively?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show that there are uncountably many linearly independent elements in $V'$? That fact can help you.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I can show that $V^{*}$, the algebraic dual, has uncountably many linearly independent elements, but not that $V'$ does.

Comment: What do you know about $V'$?

Comment: In hindsight, I wouldn't have known enough about $V'$ to give the proof Matt gave below :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(V,\left\|\cdot\right\|)$ be an infinite-dimensional normed space. We know that $V'$ is a Banach space, assuming the underlying field $\mathbb{K}$ is complete. It is a consequence of the Baire Category Theorem that the Hamel basis for any infinite-dimensional Banach space is uncountable. So let $\left\{\varphi_{\lambda}\right\}_{\Lambda}$ be a Hamel basis for $V'$, which is uncountable as $V'$ is infinite-dimensional.

Since $V$ is infinite-dimensional, it has a discontinuous linear functional $\psi$. Consider the collection of linear functionals $\left\{\psi+\varphi_{\lambda}\right\}_{\Lambda}\subset V^{*}\setminus V'$. I claim this collection is linearly independent. Indeed, for any scalars $\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n}$,

$$\alpha_{1}(\psi+\varphi_{\lambda_{1}})+\cdots+\alpha_{n}(\psi+\varphi_{\lambda_{n}})=0$$

implies that

$$\sup_{\left\|x\right\|\leq 1}\left|(\alpha_{1}+\cdots+\alpha_{n})\psi(x)\right|\leq\left|\alpha_{1}\right|\left\|\varphi_{\lambda_{1}}\right\|+\cdots+\left|\alpha_{n}\right|\left\|\varphi_{\lambda_{n}}\right\|<\infty,$$

which implies that $\alpha_{1}+\cdots+\alpha_{n}=0$. But then

$$\alpha_{1}\varphi_{\lambda_{1}}+\cdots+\alpha_{n}\varphi_{\lambda_{n}}=0,$$

which implies that $\alpha_{1}=\cdots=\alpha_{n}=0$.

We conclude that $\left\{\psi+\varphi_{\lambda}\right\}_{\Lambda}$ is an uncountable linearly independent subset of $V^{*}\setminus V'$.

Comment: Thanks Matt for this helpful answer. I think I found a slightly more elementary proof, which I'll check before posting.